# Adding a common validation to all text fields on all serializers

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am looking for a way (or several ways if needed) to add a common/shared validation function to all text fields in an DRF API.  I hope to be able to do this in the least intrusive way possible, since there are already so many serializers throughout the API.

*This is a horrible thing, and wrong, but its a requirement. Saying "don't do that" or "you shouldn't do this" is not helpful.  I know.  Its not up to me.*

Given a serializer like this:

```
class MySerializer(ModelSerializer):
    description = CharField()
    class Meta:
        model = SomeModel
        fields = ["name", "description"]
```

... both of these would somehow run a validation function.  For example, in the base CharField the framework adds two validators, and essentially I'd like to add a third.

```
class CharField(Field):  # site-packages/rest_framework/fields.py
    def __init__(self):
        ..
        self.validators.append(ProhibitNullCharactersValidator())
        self.validators.append(ProhibitSurrogateCharactersValidator())
```

Is there some clever way to do this?  I don't want to resort to literally hacking the source code, or replacing CharField throughout the application.

---

The solution I ended up going with is below. It loads at django startup in my `settings` module which has a nice `z_patches.py` where other things like this live (replacing the default filter classes, etc)

```
def wrap_init(old_init):
    @functools.wraps(old_init)
    def __new_init__(self, **kwargs):
        old_init(self, **kwargs)
        self.validators.append(MyCustomValidator())

    return __new_init__

CharField.__init__ = wrap_init(CharField.__init__)
```

Comment: Is monkey patching an option? You can override the `__init__` of `CharField` in one of your app's `AppConfig.ready` functions

Comment: I just didn't think of that before I wrote the question.  I did implement it right after posting this though, and it worked like a charm.  It happens when django settings are loaded, rather than in an app, alongside the other hacks like this :)

Comment: I do something like `CharField.__init__ = patch_func(CharField.__init__).`  If you would like to write up an answer I'm more than happy to accept it.  Also, I never thought you could do that with __init__.  I'm still not convinced its safe, but it works `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: Posted an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you absolutely know the risks, then you could do something like this in one of your `apps.py`:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig
from rest_framework.fields import Field
from rest_framework.serializers import CharField


def _init(self, **kwargs):
    ...
    Field.__init__(self, **kwargs)
    ...

    self.validators.append(YourCustomValidator())


class MyAppConfig(AppConfig):
    ...

    def ready(self):
        CharField.__init__ = _init
```

Comment: Should this capture the old init and call that directly in the wrapped function.  Charfield does a lot of work in the __init__ which is lost with this method.

Comment: I just removed them for brevity and left the important parts (run the old init, add your new validations). The old init is done by `Field.__init__(self, **kwargs)`

Comment: In your approach, what does `patch_func` do?

Comment: I've edited my question to answer that.  In this method you'd need to copy all of `CharField.__init__()`'s logic into this new function, correct?

Comment: Yes. But nevermind mine, yours looks way better. Does it work?